# understanding the process in a artwork

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

Is there any I can isolate and edit the layers to understand the steps are taken to create an AI document? For example, here's a screenshot of a basketball element AI from web and addition information in the layers panel. But I can only see it but can't edit it.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure I understand, are you wanting to edit in the Layers panel?

---

Artwork which has been expanded in Illustrator loses all it's "construction method" information. The art becomes standard vector filled shapes or stroked paths. And, in your sample image, clipping masks (which are really unnecessary for that artwork).

It can't be forensically analyzed really. The best you can do it take *educated **guesses*** at how something *may have been* constructed.

Comment: Can I edit the applied stroke and other effects?

Comment: I wanted to know if I can edit it or not. The layers panel are given here as a reference about what effects/shapes are used to create it. so my question is if I can see it, can I tweak or change it?

Comment: Well, yes. If it's an objects you can edit it. To what degree depends upon the object itself.